# UICollectionView scrollToItem breaks constraints and won't scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, interface-builder

First, here's the error message I'm getting:

```
2018-10-08 01:10:04.886509-0600 Nebula Messenger[1542:262927] [CollectionView] An attempt to prepare a layout while a prepareLayout call was already in progress (i.e. reentrant call) has been ignored. Please file a bug. UICollectionView instance is (&lt;UICollectionView: 0x10703e600; frame = (0 92; 375 491); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = &lt;NSArray: 0x281a741e0&gt;; layer = &lt;CALayer: 0x281431da0&gt;; contentOffset: {0, -8}; contentSize: {375, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {8, 0, 8, 0}&gt; collection view layout: &lt;UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x10605fe10&gt;)
2018-10-08 01:10:04.891365-0600 Nebula Messenger[1542:262927] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "&lt;NSLayoutConstraint:0x283726670 UIView:0x106065480.width == 200   (active)&gt;",
    "&lt;NSLayoutConstraint:0x283726760 UILabel:0x106065190.left == UIView:0x106065480.left + 8   (active)&gt;",
    "&lt;NSLayoutConstraint:0x2837267b0 UILabel:0x106065190.right == UIView:0x106065480.right - 8   (active)&gt;",
    "&lt;NSLayoutConstraint:0x283726850 UILabel:0x106065190.width == 200   (active)&gt;"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
&lt;NSLayoutConstraint:0x283726850 UILabel:0x106065190.width == 200   (active)&gt;
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in &lt;UIKitCore/UIView.h&gt; may also be helpful.
2018-10-08 01:10:04.896386-0600 Nebula Messenger[1542:262927] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "&lt;NSLayoutConstraint:0x28372bac0 UIView:0x1061705c0.width == 200   (active)&gt;",
    "&lt;NSLayoutConstraint:0x28372bbb0 UILabel:0x1061702d0.left == UIView:0x1061705c0.left + 8   (active)&gt;",
    "&lt;NSLayoutConstraint:0x28372bc00 UILabel:0x1061702d0.right == UIView:0x1061705c0.right - 8   (active)&gt;",
    "&lt;NSLayoutConstraint:0x28372bca0 UILabel:0x1061702d0.width == 200   (active)&gt;"
)
```

This is what I'm using to scroll:

```
func scrollToBottom() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.messagesCollection.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.messagesCollection?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 
            self.msgList.count-1, section: 0), at: 
            UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And when the view loads, I call this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.messagesCollection.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.scrollToBottom()
}
```

My first problem is the fact that it won't scroll right as it loads, I have to manually scroll it first and then it'll finish up scrolling to the bottom.

That is, unless there are a lot of cells in the CollectionView, in which case it will keep trying to scroll me back up until I fight it enough to get it scroll the other way.

The second problem (which is what seems to be the main problem) is that error message. I get a lot of them and basically it just tells me that constraints had to be broken in order to scroll, but that doesn't make any sense to me. How does scrolling break constraints?

The `scrollToBottom` function doesn't work when placed in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`.

I'm not opposed to using different methods to scroll the CollectionView, as the current method already feels kind of hacky anyway.

Comment: seems you have constraints problem on the IB

Comment: Alright, and how might the scrolling be affecting that? The scrolling, at least to my understanding shouldn't be affecting that at all...right?

Comment: well you are scrolling the View, how is it going to scroll correctly if . it has problems with its X and Y's, try to clear the console log from errors like this then try again i think it should work if you managed to fix the constrains

Comment: Okay, quick question: is it a problem that I have some constraints for the CollectionView cells set in IB and some in the code? Should I just pick one?

Comment: its better to choose one way, either the IB  or in code, but keep in mind no matter if the constraint is code or IB, you always need 1 of each bound coordinate, not 2.

Comment: Okay, so it turns out all my constraints for the objects inside the cell are actually only created programmatically, and there are no copies of any of the constraints

Comment: try to lower the priority in some of the mentioned by the log

Comment: Well, it looks like that's changing something, it's breaking different constraints. I'll go ahead and leave this question open and mess around with them more tomorrow morning.

Comment: I did totally forget to come to this, I apologize, but lowering the priorities seemed to shift everything around in a weird way so I restarted and got rid all constraints and did them purely programmatically instead of mixing, so that's probably the best answer here: Don't mix IB and programmatic constraints.